# Update a column automatically when some other column value change

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am a beginning of SQL, right now , I need to finish a task with my professor.

I have designed three tables in a database in SQL Server. I have a distance table with 5 columns that are the distance to 5 different stations. Then, I want to get the minimum distance from these 5. Then,  I want to change this cell to NULL , and in another table , I will change the status of this station from available to unavailable automatically

Actually, every time, if I get the minimum distance from distance table , I will assign this station out and put the cell null, and change the station status unavailable in another table.

So, How I design the trigger is better?

Best
Sophia

Comment: View/computed column.

Answer (score 0):

Your phrasing is a bit confusing, but in my working with MySQL everything has to be defined in detail. By 'distance' I assume you mean 'path'. Your linking the rows of your table to a distant table by listing all of the sibling/child tables it takes to reach your target. But you need at least 5-8 extra columns that are 'true' or 'false'.
One could be titled "is_access" and the other's titled "is_available", "is_changed", "is_deleted", "is_inuse", and "is_done". You will need to create a spyder (robot) in JS/PHP/Perl to monitor for this trigger you refer to. The true/false columns keep track of permissions, actions and status so the software spyder has defined 'states' to be in that put it into action until it is done.

> 1. "is_changed" acknowledges a trigger and starts your program.
> 2. The software then reads the other true/false flags to determine its actions. Their names are implicit of what they do, as they are phrased as a 'question'. "is_done" is set to false as long as the program is busy. The program changes the status of the other flags as needed. When all actions are done it sets its "is_done" flag to 'true'.
> 3. Be CAREFUL of what your program deletes. Unless the content is useless or out-dated (such as session data or a temp file), it might be better to just control access to your distant table using "is_access" and "is_available". Path length should be fixed unless another table is created that is in the same path but not the last child.
> 4. I have only touched the surface of the work to be done. Your program will have to be custom tailored to implement these actions, so I have no code to offer. Work out the steps to be done on paper first so things make sense.
> 5. You could create a table of these true/false flags. Your trigger would have your program check this table first before taking action. This could save on code and table space if your table could also point to a row of common actions instead of so much duplication in your source table.
> 6. Your program only needs to know what to do, which tables to act on (by row and column), and to update the flags it uses to determine what action to do next, if any. When it is done, it would listen for other triggers.
> 7. Your program could also be the one to add or subtract other tables in the path to the target by editing the path itself. It would not create or delete the table (that would be an SQL action, creating a trigger *if it affects paths that your program is responsible for*), just include or remove it's name in your 'distance' path. Good luck.

Comment: This answer would be a _lot_ easier to read if you break that huge wall of text up into paragraphs. You may also wish to use backquotes `\`` around things like `is_available` to make it clear that they are code entities.